# ALL except filter set in column header

Tags: excel, powerpivot, dax

A complete newbie to PowerPivot here. I have a calculated column where I count the number of distinct rows like this:

```
=COUNTROWS(
    DISTINCT(
        Data[Chain]
    )
)
```

However this does not take into account any filters manually applied in a column's header. I have 11 chains, and if I filter out all except two I want this column's value to be 2 instead of 11. How can I achieve this in PowerPivot?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add this as a measure. 
So add this to the bottom part, and it will work.

[image]